# Como capturar todos os elementos com a mesma classe de uma vez?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Estou fazendo curso de JavaScript e estou tendo muita dificuldade. Mal posso esperar pra correr pro jQuery, que nem estudei ainda, mas já consigo manipular mil vezes melhor.

Meu problema é conseguir que todas as .classes obedeçam a função, e não apenas a primeira ou uma específica ( `[x]` ). Tentei com todos os seletores, incluindo o `querySelectorAll`, mas não rolou.

Nesse exercício eu quero que todas as `span.btn` mostrem a `div#win` oculta quando clicadas.

Aproveitar pra perguntar: eu poderia parar e ir estudar jQuery no lugar do JS em si? Ou é importante continuar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Trying...</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font: normal 10pt Arial;
            margin: 0;
            background: #dbdbdb;
        }
        .track {
            padding: 5px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }
        .track span {
            border: 1px solid #212121;
            padding: 2px;
            float: right;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 10pt;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .track span:hover {
            background: rgba(206, 15, 15, 0.897);
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        #win {
            display: none;
            background: #ffffff;
            width: 200px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.384);
        }
        #win div {
            padding: 5px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 5px;
            background: #212121;
            color: #dbdbdb;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            width: 150px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tracks">
        <div class="track">Track 1<span class="btn">download</span></div>
        <div class="track">Track 2<span class="btn">download</span></div>
        <div class="track">Track 3<span class="btn">download</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="win">
        to download this track<div><strong>click here</strong></div>
    </div>

    <script>
       var janela = document.querySelector('div#win')
       var botão = document.querySelector('div#tracks').querySelector('span.track')
       botão.addEventListener('click', clicar)

       function clicar() {
            janela.style.display = 'display'
       }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JQuery deve ser encarado com auxilio e não a solução. O aprendizado do javascript vanilla é fundamental, pois caso o fabricante decidisse retirar do mercado o JQuery você ficaria incapacitado como programador.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, poxa. Vou continuar, obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para selecionar todos os elementos com a classe `.btn`, você deve utilizar o método [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), que retorna um [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Mas como esse método retorna uma lista e não o próprio elemento, você não pode esperar que a lista possua o método [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener), que só está disponível nos [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)s. Portanto, para adicionar o *listener* de evento em cada elemento retornado na lista, você deve iterar sobre a coleção, adicionando o *listener* em cada elemento.

Algo assim:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btns.forEach((btn) =>
  btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.textContent);
  })
);
```

```html
<button class="btn">Botão 1</button>
<button class="btn">Botão 2</button>
<button class="btn">Botão 3</button>
```

E como nota final:

> Mal posso esperar pra correr pro jQuery [...]

Eu questionaria a necessidade do jQuery aqui. Há alguns anos, as APIs nativas do JavaScript para manipulação do DOM eram muito pobres. Hoje em dia, novas funcionalidades foram introduzidas, além das novas versões do ECMAScript.

Vale mais a pena estudar a linguagem *pura* — livre de bibliotecas — para você entender como tudo realmente funciona. :)